# Filter a table with column values represented as rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I do not know how to phrase this question so it makes sense but the problem is probably best understood through the example below.

My table structured in such a way that an ID can have different row values:

```
PK   ID        VALUE
1    160487    10122
2    160487    MF
3    166980    10147
4    166980    MF
5    166986    10147
6    166986    MF
7    166695    10121
```

I need to select a list of the *numeric* values and corresponding ID number for every ID that have the value "MF" attributed to it:

```
PK   ID        VALUE
1    160487    10122
3    166980    10147
5    166986    10147
```

How do I approach this problem? I use SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with `IN`:

```
select *
from yourtable
where isnumeric(value) = 1
  and id in (select id from yourtable where value = 'mf')
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/848b0/1)

Answer (score 2):

If you always have two records where one has `MF` as value and the other is numeric you can use:

```
SELECT PK, ID, VALUE
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t2
             WHERE t2.ID=t.ID AND t2.VALUE='MF')
AND ISNUMERIC(t.VALUE) = 1
```

[**Sql-Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b82fc/2/0)

If you have multiple records with the same ID and with numeric values and you want to see only one you need to `GROUP BY ID` or use `ROW_NUMBER` in a CTE. However, if that's not the case above is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id IN (
SELECT DISTINCT dt.id FROM tableName dt WHERE ISNUMERIC(dt.value) = 0)
AND ISNUMERIC(value) = 1
```

Comment: this query returns also last line, which should not be returned

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to join the table to itself:

```
select t1.*
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t2.id = t1.id
    and t2.value = 'mf'
where isnumeric(t1.value)
```

If the `value` column only contains *either^ numeric values *or* 'mf', you could improve performance by changing the where clause to:

```
where t1.value != 'mf'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
SELECT *
FROM tableName WHERE ISNUMERIC(VALUE) = 1
  AND ID IN (SELE ID FROM tablewhere value = 'mf')